# Problem with webp and PHPickerViewController

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, phpickerviewcontroller

I have a simple image picker (code was found somewhere on the internet):

```
struct ImagePicker: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    @Binding var image: UIImage?

    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> PHPickerViewController {
        var config = PHPickerConfiguration()
        config.filter = .images
        let picker = PHPickerViewController(configuration: config)
        picker.delegate = context.coordinator
        return picker
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: PHPickerViewController, context: Context) {

    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }

    class Coordinator: NSObject, PHPickerViewControllerDelegate {
        let parent: ImagePicker

        init(_ parent: ImagePicker) {
            self.parent = parent
        }

        func picker(_ picker: PHPickerViewController, didFinishPicking results: [PHPickerResult]) {
            picker.dismiss(animated: true)

            guard let provider = results.first?.itemProvider else { return }

            if provider.canLoadObject(ofClass: UIImage.self) {
                provider.loadObject(ofClass: UIImage.self) { image, _ in
                    self.parent.image = image as? UIImage
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that webp images won't work. They just do not load, and `var image` does not contain anything.
Is there any way to make webp images work with my code?

I tried looking for solutions on the internet, but none of them worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can load the image as data and then create a `UIImage` from it. I guess `canLoadObject` should report true but for some reason doesn't so a workaround is needed:

```swift
// Check the identifier is WebP
if itemProvider.hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier(UTType.webP.identifier) {
    // Load it as Data
    itemProvider.loadDataRepresentation(forTypeIdentifier: UTType.webP.identifier) { data, error in
        // Convert it to UIImage
        guard let data, 
              let image = UIImage(data: data) else {
            print("Failed to load WebP data or convert it to image: \(error)")
            return
        }
        
        // Use the image!
    }
}
```

Source: https://swiftsenpai.com/development/webp-phpickerviewcontroller/